# Largest Sphere equation inside an Ellipsoid

Tags: geometry, solid-geometry

Given an ellipsoid with its equation given, how do I find the largest sphere that can be placed in the ellipsoid?

Comment: What would be your geometric intuition about this problem? Without any math, what would you say about this?

Comment: suppose equation of ellipsoid is given and i want to find the largest sphere equation enclosed by that ellipsoid.

Comment: Yes, that's what you said already in the post, and I did understand what you're asking :) But now I'm asking you, what you think of the problem.

Comment: i think the radius of Sphere equation must be less then the length of minor axis of Ellipsoid.

Comment: The sphere is centered on the ellipsoid and its radius is the smallest axis. (Conversely, the smallest enclosing sphere has the length of the major axis.)

Comment: sorry,the radius should be less than Smallest axis not equal to smallest axis.

Comment: @LawangeenKhan: why not ?

Comment: Cut a plane though the two smallest radii and try to visualize the problem in 2D.

Comment: @Yves Daoust : But i want the Exact solution;generally

Comment: @ja72 :can i try another method

Comment: [what makes you say that the radius will be less than the smallest axis](https://i.imgur.com/jrfvdMY.png)?

Comment: because i used the concept of circle inside ellipse .

Comment: Re: “i want the Exact solution; generally” You haven’t told us what sort of an equation you’re starting from. That aside, you need to find the center of the ellipsoid and its semi-axis lengths, methods for both of which you should be able to find both on MSE and in the broader Internet with some simple searches.

Comment: Derive an equation for the largest sphere that is enclosed by an ellipsoid i.e(X^2)+(4Y^2)+(3Z^2)=12.